# Value of function for given number

Tags: functions

[image]Consider the real valued function $h: \{0,1,2,...100\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $h(0)=5$, $h(100)=20$ and satisfying $h(i)=0.5[h(i+1) + h(i-1)]$, $i=1,2...99$. What is the value of $h(1)$?

[image]

Comment: So far all 8 posts of you have been problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1):

In general, a recurrence relation $a h_{n+1} + b h_n +ch_{n-1} =0 $ (with $a\neq0$) can be solved by looking for solutions of the form $h_n = \alpha^n $.  Then, $\alpha$ must satisfy the characteristic equation $ a\alpha^2 +b\alpha +c = 0$.  It usually has two distinct roots, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and all solutions are of the form $A\alpha^n + B\beta^n $.  If the roots are the same the solution is of the form $A\alpha^n + B n \alpha^n $.

In this example, the recurrence is
$$
  \frac{h_{n+1} + h_{n-1}}{2} - h_n = 0
$$
Leading to the characteristic equation
$$
  \alpha^2 -2\alpha + 1 = 0.
$$
This is a case with just one root, $\alpha = 1$, so the general solution becomes
$$
  h_n = A + Bn.
$$
It is easy to calculate from the given conditions that $A = 5$ and $B = 3/20 $.  This gives $h_1 = 103/20$.  You can readily verify the formula satisfies all the conditions.